# Google Sheets: Remove comma between specific cells in an TEXTJOIN

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using an `ARRAYFORMULA / TEXTJOIN` formula in Google Sheets to pull selected data together to make a single line of code arranged in a specific way for my project.

The resulting array needs to both **INCLUDE** commas in the first half, as well as **EXCLUDE** commas towards the end of the same formula.

[example of commas needing removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFEO2.jpg)

I'm currently using a `", "` at the beginning of my TEXTJOIN, which works for placing a  `,`  between each cell, however I also need the last few cells (in this case: I9, O5, O6, O7, O8) to not have any commas between them.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Here is a demo of what I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTQiNKy4c376FuIWQQAomlJ6J1utCOjuq6JzRplTSu4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Reddit:

If your formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(concatenate("signal code: ",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,
  $C$5:$F$5,$C$6:$F$6,$C$7:$F$7,$C$8:$F$8,$C3,$I5,$I6:L6,
  $I7:L7,$I8:L8,$I9,$O5, O6, O7, O8)))
```

Then just change the separator (in this example, a space) for those
few:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(concatenate("signal code:",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,
  $C$5:$F$5,$C$6:$F$6,$C$7:$F$7,$C$8:$F$8,$C3,$I5,$I6:L6,$I7:L7,
  $I8:L8)& " " & TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, $I9, $O5, O6, O7, O8)))
```

Comment: Rather than the word "solved", when allowed, apply the green checkmark to indicate your "accepted" answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

### Option 01

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,C5:F8),
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,C3,I5))&", "&
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,I6:L9)&" "&
          TEXTJOIN(" ",1,O5:O8)
```

[image]

### Option 02

**Use this formula** to replace the last set of commas

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B12, 
              REGEXEXTRACT(B12&"", " --ar.+?(,.+)"), 
              REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(B12&"", " --ar.+?(,.+)"), ",", ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler formula (based on [your formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758241/1527780))

```
=INDEX(concatenate("signal code: ",
  TEXTJOIN(", ",1,C5:C8,C3,I5:I8) & " " 
& TEXTJOIN(" ", 1,I9, O5, O6, O7, O8)))
```